# -webkit-transform roation and position absolute left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a function that sets rotation css styles through jquery. I also have another function that's setting the left position of the div using the same t.css({left:pos}) setup. This all works perfectly in ever browser except Safari. 
Has anyone had any problems with this. If I remove the rotation styles the left positioning works.
When I view the animation in safari developer tools I can see both the rotation and the left attributes on the div tag are getting dynamically updated but it doesn't not render the position attribute only the rotation.

```
function rotate(rotation){
t.css({'-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)','-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)','-ms-transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)','-o-transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)','transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)'
});
}
```

Comment: Is the left position also set through a transform (i.e. translate)?

Comment: Separate function that just passes in the position.

Comment: Can you provide more code and put it somewhere like JSFiddle?

Comment: Hmm I just set the position to relative and it works. I had it set to absolute and it didn't odd. There is far too much code to break out into jsfiddle so sorry can't post it. But looks like the relative did the trick not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

```
var rotation = 45;
var t = $('div');

t.css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)',
    'transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)'
});
```

​

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YQxBg/1/

Please can you upload a full demonstration of it not working correctly for us to investigate?